# Breeze and mobile memory management

Tags: memory-management, breeze

At what point do references to EntityManager containers in memory get released in a mobile browser app?  Does getting out of the browser app release this cache memory?  I realize I can do an EntityManger.clear(), but of course, users will often just cut out of the mobile browser.  So how can I know if the cache memory of this container is released?  Is there a tool to observe this?  I'm wondering if I need to concern myself with the concept of garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

If by "getting out of the browser app" you mean either navigating away from the hosting web page or closing the browser ... yes, either will release all memory formerly consumed by the app.